# Active Directory LDAP query used to retrieve GPO folders are missing few columns, Any alternative solution to it

Tags: active-directory, ldap-query, gpo

We have a vb script which uses LDAP query to get the grouppolicycontainers , this uses columns of cn, versionnumber.
Recently I found that these columns are no more available to query. We are using this data to find out AD is in sync with physical GPO folders are not.
Do we have any alternative solution.
LDAP QUERY: <LDAP://localhost/CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=”Domain start name”,DC=”Domain end name”>;(objectCategory=groupPolicyContainer);cn,versionNumber;subtree
Thanks in advance.

I tried to query through ADSI tool and found only available columns are Name, class and DistinguishedName are available as of now.